# Ruby on rails cannot access http:/localhost:3000 on MAC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, macos, localhost

I am trying to learn Ruby on Rails, I have followed the instructions from this page to get rails installed on my MAC.
Everything is working so far, but localhost:3000 is not working.
I also try SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222 but not working.

I am trying to find out what is the problem and make it work.
Dose some one know how to fix it?

Rails  4.2.0
Ruby   2.0.0p598 (2014-11-13 revision 48408) [x86_64-darwin13.4.0]

```
$ vagrant up
enter code here

==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...

==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...

==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat

==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 3000 => 3000 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)

==> default: Booting VM...

==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...

==> default: Machine booted and ready!
GuestAdditions 4.3.20 running --- OK.

==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...

==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/Arturo/Desktop/Vagrant/myVM

==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
```

it come up like this

```
   $ rails server

=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-01-12 07:41:04] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-01-12 07:41:04] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux]
[2015-01-12 07:41:04] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3021 port=3000
```

I can't find any error to fix.
could some one tell me from where to start to fix.

Vagrantfile

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "centos64box"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.network :"forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  #　config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10”

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Define a Vagrant Push strategy for pushing to Atlas. Other push strategies
  # such as FTP and Heroku are also available. See the documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/push/atlas.html for more information.
  # config.push.define "atlas" do |push|
  #   push.app = "YOUR_ATLAS_USERNAME/YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  #   sudo apt-get update
  #   sudo apt-get install -y apache2
  # SHELL
end
```

Comment: So you run `rails server` on your vagrant machine, right? What is this machine IP? Show your `Vagrantfile`.

Comment: Why don't you paste it in question?

Comment: Stop spamming comments. Paste it in question instead. Code pasted in comments is unreadable and therefore, almost useless. I'm not gonna read through it.

Comment: Sorry This is only way I could figure it out to right your Answer!!

Yes, I'm using Vagrant and Vagrantfile will be up there
The machine IP will be 180.48.60.1

thanks for all

Comment: No, you could (and you should have) edit your question. What if you try to go to `180.48.60.1:3000` in browser?

Comment: I tried 180.48.60.1:3000 with Chrome and it says
"this webpage in not available"

Comment: Just to be clear, you are trying to go to `http://localhost:3000` not `http:/localhost:3000` right?

Answer (score 0):

SSH into your vagrant and run this command:

```
ipaddr
```

Take the vagrant ip address from there. Run rails server and in your browser

```
vagrant-ip-address:3000
```